# implementation 'com.hold1:keyboardheightprovider:0.0.9'

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk, apk

This error IS IN A photo editing applications I closed offline gradel mode and it didn't work Knowing and i change the gradel didn't work too that

when I click run or trying to upload the APK

I get this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.hold1:keyboardheightprovider:0.0.9.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve com.hold1:keyboardheightprovider:0.0.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/crysis21/Android/com/hold1/keyboardheightprovider/0.0.9/keyboardheightprovider-0.0.9.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/crysis21/Android/com/hold1/keyboardheightprovider/0.0.9/keyboardheightprovider-0.0.9.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I know that's the error is from
com.hold1:keyboardheightprovider:0.0.9.

but I don't know what I can do
please help

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in 1.0.3. there was a mistake in generated Gradle POM. update dependency in your project.

`implementation 'ro.holdone:keyboardheightprovider:1.0.3`

Comment: Where should i add this code? I can't build my project and its running me crazy!
And how do i get rid of this package? I uninstalled it and yet i get this anoying error.
Please help